# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 - Magento Multistore

Tags: magento, mysql-error-1064

I have a magento multi store setup, and I must've done something wrong while creating/deleting store views, as now I get the error below when trying to reindex catalog_url_rewrite. Anyone have any idea of things I can try?

```
  2013-08-21T16:45:46+00:00 ERR (3): 
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myserver`.`core_url_rewrite`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE C)' in /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
    #1 /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #2 /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #3 /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #4 /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
    #5 /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
    #6 /home/myserver/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1910): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
    #7 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(300): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('core_url_rewrit...', Array)
    #8 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(293): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveRewrite(Array, NULL)
    #9 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(320): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), '/', false)
    #10 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(461): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), NULL, false)
    #11 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(254): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshCategoryRewrite('318', '130', false)
    #12 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('130')
    #13 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
    #14 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
    #15 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
    #16 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(178): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
    #17 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
    #18 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
    #19 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #20 /home/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #21 /home/myserver/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #22 /home/myserver/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #23 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have deleted some store ID or store.

This will happen if store ID does not exist in 'core_store' table.

Comment: I did, should I just add a row with store ID for that store to resolve the problem or will that further my headache? I notice I still have catalog_product_flat_131 even though that store doesn't exist in 'core_store'

Comment: Delete all flat tables for which store id does not exist.You need to check previous data for entry on core_store table missing and insert one.